# Android Menu Group Checkable

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I currently am programming for API 10 and above. I created a menu and was looking to implement the method Menu.setGroupCheckable(id, checkable, exclusive). Below is my code. From the documentation I was expecting a check mark over the selected item out of the group and the other ones to be disabled. However, this is not the case.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     menu.add(0, 1, 0, "I1").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
     menu.add(0, 2, 1, "I2");
     menu.add(0,3,2,"I3");

     menu.add(1, 4, 3, "I4");
     menu.add(1, 5, 4, "I5");
     menu.add(1,6,5,"I6");

    menu.setGroupCheckable(1, true, true);

     return true;
}
```

---

Android documentation link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Menu: Two single-checkable groups in the same menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698954/android-menu-two-single-checkable-groups-in-the-same-menu)

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/28673.aspx

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/07/android-options-menu-submenu-group.html

http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/09/26/android-tutorial-how-to-add-a-menu-programmatic-vs-declarative-solution/

These links may help you!!!

Comment: I ended up doing the id assignment in Java, but used the code from the first link for the onOptionsItemSelected Callback.

Answer (score 0):

use Updated lib

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'