# Android Menu:How to enable a submenu in a menugroup from xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a menugroup "Mode", which has 2 submenu items under it (Admin and User). When my app is fired, I wanted "Admin" to be enabled by default(I added Android:enabled="true" under Admin, but it didnt help)

From the  link [Android Menu Group Checkable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720427/android-menu-group-checkable?rq=1) I understand that I can do it from the source code. But I want to do it from .xml file. How?

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_first"
                    android:title="Mode"
                    android:orderInCategory="1"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    app:showAsAction="never"/>

              <group android:id="@+id/floating_group"
                     android:checkableBehavior="single"
                     android:visible="true">
                    <item android:id="@+id/admin"
                          android:title="\tAdmin"
                          android:orderInCategory="1"
                          android:enabled="true"
                          app:showAsAction="never"/>

                    <item android:id="@+id/user"
                          android:title="\tUser"
                          android:orderInCategory="2"
                          app:showAsAction="never"/>
              </group>
```

Comment: All items are enabled true by default, I think you want is android:checked="true"

Comment: worked like charm. Post this as answer, for me to accept/close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, what you need to add is **android:checked="true"** like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/admin"
 android:title="\tAdmin"
 android:orderInCategory="1"
 android:checked="true"
 app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Hope this helped!