# Having two single-selection groups in ActionBar doesn't work, but attaching a pop up menu instead doesn't work either

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am writing an Android app where the user must choose how and what to display on a graph. These options are expressed in **two single-selection menu groups (radio buttons), both of which should be accessible from the action bar.**

The first group works fine. It's added at the end of my ActionBar XML like this:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:showAsAction="never" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_choice_1" android:title="Choice 1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_choice_2" android:title="Choice 2" android:checked="true"/>
</group>
```

**When I add a second `<group>` below the first one, however, the two merge** into one single-selection list. In other words, the options from both lists are rendered together and if I choose an option pertaining to the first list, I cannot choose anything from the second.

Instead, I want **two separate lists** of radio buttons. My next idea was to add another button the ActionBar that, when clicked, would **launch a [pop-up menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)**. But when I click the button, I get an `IllegalStateException`, saying that my "MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor".

Here is my attempted pop-up menu code:

In my ActionBar XML:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_openothermenu"
  android:title="@string/openothermenustr"
  android:showAsAction="always" />
```

My new menu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_2_choice_1" android:title="@string/2_choice_1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_2_choice_2" android:title="@string/2_choice_2" android:checked="true"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Code in my Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.openothermenu:
        Menu m = (Menu) findViewById(R.menu.other_menu);
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.menu.main_menu));
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.other_menu, popup.getMenu());
        /* This commented block doesn't work either, and prevents execution
        // Restore saved chosen value
        int chosen = settings.getInt(MENU_2_PREFS, -1);
        switch(chosen)
        {
            case 1:
                m.findItem(R.id.menu_1_choice_1).setChecked(true);
                updateVisibleThings();
                break;
            default:
            case 2:
                m.findItem(R.id.menu_2_choice_2).setChecked(true);
                updateOtherVisibleThings();
                break;
        }
        */
        popup.show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_2_choice_1:
        if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
        else item.setChecked(true);
        updateVisibleThings();

        // save chosen setting
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt(MENU_2_PREFS, 1);
        editor.commit(); // Commit the edits!

        return true;
    case R.id.menu_2_choice_2:
        if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
        else item.setChecked(true);
        updateOtherVisibleThings();

        // save chosen setting
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt(MENU_2_PREFS, 2);
        editor.commit(); // Commit the edits!

        return true;
    default:
        return true;
    }
}
```

**How can I create two sets of checkable menu items such that both are attached to the ActionBar?**

Comment: Please see the answer to this question:<br> <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698954/android-menu-two-single-checkable-groups-in-the-same-menu>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found an elegant way to solve this that was unfortunately not in the documentation. Add the following code to your ActionBar menu XML:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_openothermenu"
      android:title="@string/openothermenustr"
      android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_2_choice_1" android:title="@string/2_choice_1"  android:showAsAction="never" />
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_2_choice_2" android:title="@string/2_choice_2"  android:showAsAction="never" android:checked="true" />
        </group>
     </menu>
</item>
```

No extra handler code or popup menu implementation is necessary for such a menu to appear.

Comment: this works great! you must insert the snippet into the correct menu xml ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> [...] </menu>```