# Android - Can not use popup in Fragment

Tags: android, popup, fragment

I am new to android. Now I am trying to create a slider bar. Now I have created a slider bar. Now I want to show popup when I click the icon in Action bar. 
When I extents activity the popup is working fine. But when I change into extents Fragment I can not use the popup. Please let me know any idea or any example for popup in Fragment page.

```
public void popup_window() {
    View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu_popup);
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_, popupMenu.getMenu());

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {  
                case R.id.action_ticket:  
                    Intent intdn = new Intent(List_Activity.this,List_Activity.class);
                    intdn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                   
                    startActivity(intdn);
                  break;    

                case R.id.action_survey:  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Under Construction ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    break;      
                case R.id.action_service_request:  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Under Construction ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    break;  

                  default: 
                      break;  

            }  
             return true;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

I am getting error:-
[image: Error Image]

Lots of error. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

LogCat Error Message:-

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:101)
at android.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:108)
at com.example.sample.Testing_Fragment1.popup_window(Testing_Fragment1.java:262)
at com.example.sample.Testing_Fragment1.onOptionsItemSelected(Testing_Fragment1.java:227)
at android.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1801)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1959)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2551)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: For the popup menu required activity context so Replace all context with getActivity() in fragment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> When I extents activity the popup is working fine. But when I change
>   into extents Fragment I can not use the popup.

you can call `findViewById()` directly for `Activity`, however as you are using a `Fragment`, youo will need a view object to call `findViewById()`.
eg. getView().findViewById();

1. [View - findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int))
2. [Activity - findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))

   [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) --This will return the root view for the fragment, with this you can call `findViewById()`

> new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);

Here popup menu requires `Context`, passed as first parameter. You can use `this` if you are in activity, however in Fragment you need to use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

[PopupMenu(Context context, View anchor)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

> new Intent(List_Activity.this,List_Activity.class);

this is wrong, Actually it should be package context and class

`packageContext` ---    A Context of the application package implementing this class.

`class`  ---      The component class that is to be used for the intent.

Use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` instead of just `getApplicationContext()` whenever you want to display `Toast` from `Fragment`

So your code will look like

```
public void popup_window() {

View menuItemView = getView().findViewById(R.id.menu_popup);
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), menuItemView);
popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_, popupMenu.getMenu());

popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {  
            case R.id.action_ticket:  
                Intent intdn = new Intent(getActivity(),List_Activity.class); // Your nxt activity name instead of List_Activity
                intdn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                   
                getActivity().startActivity(intdn);
              break;    

            case R.id.action_survey:  
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Under Construction ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                break;      
            case R.id.action_service_request:  
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Under Construction ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                break;  

              default: 
                  break;  

        }  
         return true;
    }
});
popupMenu.show();
}
```

UPDATE:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used
>   without an anchor

You get this exception because the Anchor view for this popup is null I guess. Hence whenever system tries to show the popup, it gives you this exception.

Just check the `tryShow()` in 
[MenuPopupHelper](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/shoppinglist/ShoppingList/src/org/openintents/shopping/ui/widget/backport/MenuPopupHelper.java?r=3810)

Also refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505362/having-two-single-selection-groups-in-actionbar-doesnt-work-but-attaching-a-po) on SO by **Maxim Zaslavsky**

Comment: Hi @Ritesh Gune.. Thanks for the detailed explanation.. Now I have cleared all the error. But Pop is not showing when I click the icon.?

Comment: Force closed When I click the icon.

Comment: could you plz post the stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @Ritesh Gune.. I add the LogCat Error message in my original post.

Comment: **popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {**   Here only I am getting error.

Comment: Hi @Ritesh Gune. I refer both suggestion. But can't find Answer. :-(. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @RiteshGune you have mention why developer got this type of issue. But is there any solution to that? if there is then please update it here.....

Answer (score 1):

Problem is popup or dialogs are associated with 'Activity' , you need the Activity context here. But this refers to your 'Fragment'.

One way is to pass the `Activity` context when you create the instance of Fragment or use the `getActivity` method of the `Fragment` which will return the activity context.

So change your code like this

```
     public void popup_window() {
View menuItemView = getView().findViewById(R.id.menu_popup);
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), menuItemView);
popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_, popupMenu.getMenu());

popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {  
            case R.id.action_ticket:  
                Intent intdn = new Intent(getActivity(),List_Activity.class);
                intdn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                   
                startActivity(intdn);
              break;    

            case R.id.action_survey:  
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Under Construction ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                break;      
            case R.id.action_service_request:  
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Under Construction ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                break;  

              default: 
                  break;  

        }  
         return true;
       }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Libin.. Thanks for your effort. Now no error in coding. But when I click the icon the app force closed.

Comment: Hi @Libin.. **popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {** I am getting error here.

Comment: if your using support android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu make sure     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" . Let me know

Comment: Correct answer！

Answer (score 1):

Another problem that easily happens with PopupMenus is the calling menu entry is hidden in the three dots (overflow menu). These entries can't have a popupmenu anchored to it.

This is what I had first and got the java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_entry_to_show_popupmenu"
 app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

and what I needed is

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_entry_to_show_popupmenu"
 app:showAsAction="always" />
```

My full popupmenu setup function from an activity begins like this:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), getActivity().findViewById(R.id.menu_filter));
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_tasks, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    [...]
    popup.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use instead of this : ***getApplicationContext()***

use this : ***My_Activity.this***

Answer (score 0):

use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` inside fragment.

Comment: Hi @Mohd Mufiz.. Thanks for your reply.. **PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);** Still error in this line. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: use PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), menuItemView);

Comment: Now all the error cleared. But App getting force close when I click the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity, menuItemView);
```