# MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor

Tags: android, android-toolbar, popupmenu, optionmenu

I want add `PopupMenu` to my `MenuItem`.

*Menu.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/date"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Date"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/category"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Category"
        android:visible="true"/>
</menu>
```

When I click on `MenuItem` I call this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.filter_action) {
        showPopup(item.getActionView());
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.filter_billing_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

And I get this exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: 1. Do you call PopupMenu from Activity or Fragment?
2. Is this menu button visible on screen?

Comment: @DanilOnyanov in fragment

Comment: Did you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539792/android-can-not-use-popup-in-fragment?

Comment: The constructor for PopupMenu needs an anchor view to decide its showing position. You have to pass a non-null view to the second argument for PopupMenu().

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm reading "internet" and I try this code:

```
showPopu(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.filter_action));
```

Instead

```
showPopup(item.getActionView());
```

It's works for me

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 22):

I believe a better (and simpler) approach in this case would be to define a submenu instead of creating a `PopupMenu`.

For example:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:title="menu" >
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/item_in_submenu_1"
              android:title="subitem1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/item_in_submenu_2"
              android:title="subitem2" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I had

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_entry_to_show_popupmenu"
 app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

and what I needed is

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_entry_to_show_popupmenu"
 app:showAsAction="always" />
```

showAsAction="always" is needed. A menu entry hidden in the three dots (overflow menu) can't have a popupmenu anchored to it.

My full popupmenu setup function begins like this:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), getActivity().findViewById(R.id.menu_filter));
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_tasks, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    [...]
    popup.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your this code:

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

to this:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```