# show popup menu in android when longclickitem recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
 public void onRecyclerViewItemLongClicked(final int position, int id) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this,binding.rcvPrefix.getChildAt(position));
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_rcv,popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.item_add:
                    createDialogAdd();
                    initializeRCV();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.item_edit:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.item_delete:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    db.deletePrefix(prefixList.get(position));
                    prefixList.remove(position);
                    initializeRCV();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

//error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.tiny.covertphonenum, PID: 13363
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor
                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:125)
                      at android.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:218)
                      at com.example.tiny.covertphonenum.view.MainActivity.onRecyclerViewItemLongClicked(MainActivity.java:291)
                      at com.example.tiny.covertphonenum.presenter.adapter.AdapterRcvPrefix$1.onLongClick(AdapterRcvPrefix.java:49)
                      at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5237)
                      at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21121)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I try show popup menu when long click item but error when item have position=10.please help me

Comment: you are passing a wrong anchor check your anchor or view you are passing for pop up menu to show

Comment: may be item does not exist at position 10, just pass the view which is long pressed in your callback and pass it as anchor

Comment: I check x,y of binding  on the outside of the screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346984/menupopuphelper-cannot-be-used-without-an-anchor

Answer (score 0):

Call `getChildAt` in `RecyclerView` to get the child item is not a proper way due to the way `RecyclerView` create/recycle the children base on scroll offset. To get the child item at a specific position, make sure that item is currently visible on screen (not recycled) or the result is null. Call this method:

```
ViewHolder viewHolder = rcvPrefix.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
```

Check for null before using the result `viewHolder`, then use `viewHolder.itemView` to be the anchor view.

Answer (score 0):

Create interface like this

```
public interface OnLongClickListener {
    void onLongClick(int position);
}
```

and set to adapter of recyclerview like in constructor or by calling setmethod

and pass code in onbindview

```
holder.llParent.setTag(position);
holder.llParent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
           int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
           onClickListener.onClick(position);
           return false;
      }
});
```

where llparent is linearlayout of parent layout of recyclerview's items..

Answer (score 0):

Although quite a long time passed, I recently encountered this issue. In my case I had the same problem when clicking the button on last RecyclerView element for popup menu. It was half-visible so, apparently the Recyclerview has recycled it. The problem resolved by passing holder view to the popup menu initialize method. So, instead of

```
public void onRecyclerViewItemLongClicked(final int position, int id) {
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this,binding.rcvPrefix.getChildAt(position));
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_rcv,popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
....
```

use

```
public void onRecyclerViewItemLongClicked(View view, final int position, int id) {
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_rcv,popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
.....
```

So, you need to pass the view you clicked through your interface in addition to your data.

```
holder.llParent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
       int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
       onClickListener.onRecyclerViewItemLongClicked(v, position, id)
       return false;
  }
});

public interface OnLongClickListener {
void onRecyclerViewItemLongClicked(View v, int position, int id);
}
```